# In maven, how can I refer to a parent pom that does not exist at that location on the file system?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, parent-child, nexus

I didn't realize this was possible to do, but apparently it is because this project I inherited does it.  The project's pom looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</parent>
```

That "../parent/pom.xml" *does not* exist on my file system, yet this project builds without issue.  Even Intellij is confused and marks this `relativePath` in red.

I know this has something to do with the way my ~/.m2/settings.xml is configured, because the project did not build and complained about the missing pom.xml until I used the company's settings.xml.  But I'm not sure where in that file it is making this work.

Can someone point me to some documentation that describes how this feature works?    We are using the Nexus maven repository.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question asks "how can I do this" and then the description says you're already doing it just fine. Is something broken, or do you just want to know how it works?

Comment: Maybe posting the provided settings.xml would help?  This does seem to be an odd way of doing things.

Comment: @dcsohl I just want to know how it works.  Note that I did not set up any part of this, so I don't know how it's done.  I'm just working with it.

Comment: @aglassman I don't feel comfortable doing that because of the company information in the file.  But it doesn't have anything that stands out to me.  It seems like it may be a configuration in the `repository` that makes this possible, if I were to guess.  We're using nexus.

Comment: My guess is that the parent project is pulled form the nexus repository.  Inspect the parent project, and I bet it contains that path.

Comment: @aglassman the parent project contains that path to what?

Comment: The parent pom.xml.  Usually you don't need to specify the pom location for a parent project, but maybe they used some non-standard folder structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Maven goes looking for the parent POM, it first looks in the place specified by `<relativePath/>` (which is `../pom.xml` by default); if it cannot be found there, it goes and looks in your local repository (`~/.m2`) and then tries to download it from the remote repository.

Without seeing your `settings.xml` it is impossible for me to be sure but my best guess is you have a remote repository listed there that made it possible for maven to perform that last step - download the parent POM from a remote repository that is defined in settings.xml.

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance  - "Notice the `relativePath` element. It is not required, but may be used as a signifier to Maven to first search the path given for this project's parent, before searching the local and then remote repositories."

Comment: Ah, I did not know that.  Would you be able to provide documentation or a screenshot to how you can configure nexus to do this?

Comment: It's not really a matter of configuring nexus to do anything. All it has to do is serve up a POM that corresponds to the "coordinates" (groupID, artifactID, version, classifier) that you've said your parent POM should be located at. You just need to configure Maven to use your local nexus as a remote repository that it should consult when looking for artifacts.

Comment: Ah, interesting, you are correct: If I comment out the relative path, it still builds correctly.  I guess that `relativePath` was really throwing me off.